# Logcat not showing anything android api level 22

Tags: java, android, logcat

I have problem with Logcat.
 Logcat not showing anything only if I use some device with Android API level 22.
I use Android Studio.I did: change ADB location on device,kill adb server, restart Logcat, Invalidies caches/restart, reinstal Device, reset Android Studio /Computer. nothing solved problem.

Comment: you must have accidentally set up a filter, on top of the logcat menu

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the correct device in the Logcat?

[image]

I've faced the same problem once and it was just that...

Comment: I did it and nothing.

Comment: If I use another Android API level, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

1) Ensure you have selected your device you are working on

2) Ensure your app package name is selected

3) Ensure 'vebose' is selected to show all logcat messages

4) No filter is applied

[image]

Comment: I did it and nothing.

Comment: If I use another Android API level, everything is ok.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting your device (or if emulator turning it off) and restarting?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing of above helped then:

1- close the emulator.

2- Start the emulator.

3-be sure that no process is selected , like this [image]

4-Run your project.